# Magento “File was not uploaded”. Random bug

Tags: php, magento, file-upload

We have a random bug when we try to upload product images through admin.
For example we upload 12 images for a determined product.  After I browse the files and click upload files, for example, 6 images are uploaded and no the others with the error "file was not uploaded".

If we try to upload again 4 images are uploaded and the others 2 no. The problem isn't the files because in occasions fails and other times are ok. And also depend of the pcs because some gives error and others no.

In the file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php I have changed the exception in the  function `__construct($fileId)` with  `throw new Exception('File was not uploaded.', $code);`
and it display always `$code=0` which is the correct value.

Its a very strange bug.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".